# PowerShell Cannot find drive (local drive)

Tags: powershell

I am running a command to delete old log files from a server.  It works in the PowerShell console.  But when I put it into a scrpt and run it I get an error.  The commands:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\Software\logs\log" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item

Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\Software\logs\services\service" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item
```

The error I get is:
[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzRyV.jpg)
[image]
What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Windows Server 2016 Standard Please help.

Tried the commands in the PowerShell console and they work.  Tried putting one command in the script, but it stilll did not work.

Comment: Did you copy paste the command from a text processor or a web page? The error indicates that something other than a `-` is being used in front of `Path`. Try manually typing the command into your prompt instead

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `–` (U+2013,  *En Dash*) for introducing parameter name(s), as in `–Path`.

[The name of the parameter is preceded by a hyphen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#long-description) `-` (U+002D,  *Hyphen-Minus*), which signals to PowerShell that the word following the hyphen is a parameter name.

Use `-Path`.

**BTW**, you can see following [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case in your screenshot:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetBytes('–Path'))
```

> ```
> â€“Path
> ```